# how to filter elements from an array with respect to another array?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, break

```
array('5','6','3')

array('3','2','1','5','9','0','6')
```

I need the elements of 2nd array  removing the elements matching  from the first array. ie. 
`array('2','1','9','0')`

please help.

Comment: have you tried [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)?

Comment: i didn't..this is exactly what i want, thank you so much.

Comment: well, you know what to do next time ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use array_diff

```
<?php 
$array1=array('5','6','3');
$array2=array('3','2','1','5','9','0','6');
$diff = array_diff($array2, $array1);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($diff);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 1
    [4] => 9
    [5] => 0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `array_diff` in `PHP` that will compare arrays and returns the difference

```
$diffarray= array_diff($array2, $array1);
```